# Is it possible to access recaptcha from port forwarding?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I port forwarded my php script from my localhost to my proxy server. I am able to access all part of my script on the proxy server beside the reCaptcha(it result inERROR for site owner:Invalid domain for site key) I know the site key is correct.

I believe the problem is that I am allowing access to my inital url, so when I'm requesting the Captcha from my proxy it result in the Invalid domain. How do I go about letting google reCaptcha give access to the proxy server too. Is this a script problem or an Apache web server issue?

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what you are trying to describe. What is posted to where? What is your actual code? Why should a reference somehow be interfered by a port forwarding?

Comment: I think I figure out the problem. When I access my php script from my port fowarded proxy. I'm sending request to reCaptcha from my proxy server, not the multiple remote server I had set up in the original script. How do I go about redirecting the same request from those remote server on my proxy

Comment: It looks like you completely rewrote your question. Please clearly mark updates in the question to prevent additional confusion.

Comment: And again your description in that comment above is confusing. What "multiple remote server"? I am afraid you will not really get answers with such confusing descriptions. No one is willing to invest time into trying to _guess_ what you _might_ be trying to explain. It clearly is in the interest of the person asking a question to phrase the question such that it is easy to understand and a pleasure to read. This is a general aspect of human communication, btw.